# Excel to csv file conversion - conserve numbers after the decimal point

Tags: excel, csv

When converting a xls file to a csv file using 'Save as...' in Excel (which will then be imported into R), the csv output file systematically drops all numbers after the decimal point e.g. 1.0524 becomes 1, 5.213 becomes 5 and so on.

How can I prevent this which obviously leads to problems of accuracy over a large number of data entries?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the data in your Excel cells are really floating point numbers conforming to the decimal settings of your computer?

Comment: Excel doesn't silently truncate floats. Which version are you using? Which country? What delimiter does your CSV library expect?

Comment: I'm using the french version of Excel 2010 - the delimiter is a ;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel doesn't do that. However, it's pretty common for non-US users to stumble over Excel's CSV output format.

In the US, Excel uses a `.` for a decimal point and `,` as a CSV separator (obviously, it's called comma-separated values for a reason).

In many European countries, Excel uses a `,` for a decimal point and `;` as a CSV separator (according to the countries' conventions for decimal notation).

If you try to read an EU CSV file with a US CSV library, you'll get mixed-up field values for obvious reasons.

So, for example in R you need to tell your CSV reader this:

```
table = read.csv2(file, sep = ";", quote = "\"", dec = ",")
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, what is the prefered way to read data into R from an Excel file? It is best to convert to a tab delimited text file than a csv file?

Comment: Use `read.csv2()` for that. It allows you to specify the separator and decimal point character. Type `help(read.csv)` at the prompt for the documentation.