# Excel to csv file error

Tags: excel, csv

The data: 56489x197 z-Values for a contour Plot.

I am encountering major problems when exporting en excel file to csv.
In the original data the maximum value is 3,149, but in the exported csv. file I recive values up to 9998. I guess that somehow a dot got lost... for example, it converted 0.9998 to 9998.

How can I be sure that it convertes the content correctly?

I did not find any help on the internet.

Comment: It seems to be a mismatch of decimal sign and thousand separator between your file and your regional settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel to csv file conversion - conserve numbers after the decimal point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097597/excel-to-csv-file-conversion-conserve-numbers-after-the-decimal-point)